# Comparing pairs of unique column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
name   group  feedback     question
a      g1     False        abc
a      g1     True         abc
a      g1     True         xyz
b      g1     True         xyz
b      g1     True         abc
c      g1     False        def
d      g2     False        xyz
d      g2     True         xyz
e      g2     True         xyz
```

I am trying to do a statistic that contains the number of questions answered by each group (it doesn't matter how many times), the total number of questions, the number of questions answered by both groups and the ratio between mutual questions and total questions:

```
Team1 Team2 NumberQuestionsT1 NumberQuestionsT2 AllQuestions CommonQuestions  Ratio 
g1    g2                    3                 1            4               1   0.25
```

What I did was actually counting unique values "manually" with `groupby`, `nunique` etc, because it's simple when the `group` column has only two distinct values. However, **is it possible to compare pairs of two groups and build dataframes with one row like above if my dataframe has many `group`s**? Example:

```
name   group  feedback     question
a      g1     False        abc
a      g1     True         abc
a      g1     True         xyz
b      g1     True         xyz
b      g1     True         abc
c      g1     False        def
d      g2     False        xyz
d      g2     True         xyz
e      g2     True         xyz
f      g3     True         abc
f      g3     True         www
g      g3     False        xyz
h      g4     True         www
h      g4     True         qqq
i      g4     False        xyz
```

So I would want to compare `g1` with `g2`, `g1` with `g3`, `g1` with `g4`, `g2` with `g3` and `g3` with `g4`.

```
Team1 Team2 NumberQuestionsT1 NumberQuestionsT2 AllQuestions CommonQuestions  Ratio 
g1    g2                    3                 1            4               1   0.25 
g1    g3                    3                 3            4       2           0.50
g1    g4                    3                 3            4               1   0.25 
g2    g3                    1                 3            4       1           0.25
g2    g4                    1                 3            4       1           0.25
g3    g4                    3                 3            4               2   0.50
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy I did, I will try to format it asap since I am on mobile now. But I hope I didn't make any computation mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt.  First, find the set of questions answered for each group:

```
>>> g = df.groupby('group')['question'].apply(set)
>>> g
group
g1    {xyz, abc, def}
g2              {xyz}
g3    {xyz, abc, www}
g4    {qqq, xyz, www}
Name: question, dtype: object
```

Then, use `itertools` to get the combinations you want, computing the indices for each desired column:

```
import itertools

g = df.groupby('group')['question'].apply(set) # as above
rows = []
total = len(df.question.unique())

for a, b in itertools.combinations(g.index, 2):
    rows.append({'Team1':a,
                 'Team2':b,
                 'NumberQuestionsT1':len(g[a]),
                 'NumberQuestionsT2':len(g[b]),
                 'AllQuestions': total,
                 'CommonQuestions': len(g[a] & g[b]),
                 'Ratio': len(g[a] & g[b]) / total})
output = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Giving:

```
  Team1 Team2  NumberQuestionsT1  NumberQuestionsT2  AllQuestions  \
0    g1    g2                  3                  1             5   
1    g1    g3                  3                  3             5   
2    g1    g4                  3                  3             5   
3    g2    g3                  1                  3             5   
4    g2    g4                  1                  3             5   
5    g3    g4                  3                  3             5   

   CommonQuestions  Ratio  
0                1    0.2  
1                2    0.4  
2                1    0.2  
3                1    0.2  
4                1    0.2  
5                2    0.4
```

I've replace the `AllQuestions` calculation with the one you commented.  Now, it seems like the difference is that your example input has 5 question types (`abc`, `def`, `qqq`, `www`, `xyz`)?

I couldn't think of a way to do this without `itertools`, and I am also using a for loop for the initial determination of every `set` of questions.  So I reckon there could be a significantly faster method, but this may be sufficient given the size of your data.

Comment: wouldn't allquestions be `len(g[a] | g[b])` (the set union)?

Comment: @AsishM. I had that initially, but it seems like that also doesn't give the desired result, unless I am missing something

Comment: true, you're right. I missed the initial examples

Comment: This works except, indeed, the total number of questions! This is just the number of unique values in the question column (see it as how many questions exist/are available overall). I'm trying to do it right now.

Comment: I can't edit your answer, but I'm pretty sure one can just use `len(df.question.unique())`.

Comment: @futuredataengineer gotcha - I get 5 Q types instead of 4, is that right?

Comment: @Tom indeed, my mistake!